# Getting Error When Installing Node-Mapnik on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: node.js, npm, mapnik

why i get this error message everytime i try to install node-mapnik on my computer. i use windows 8.1 x64.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Adi Arta Wibawa\
\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mapnik@3.
x"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! mapnik@3.4.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mapnik@3.4.7 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallb
ack-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mapnik package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mapnik
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\WebDev\ProjectOne\npm-debug.log
```

what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in the node-mapnik readme [here](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik#windows-specific) and [here](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/wiki/WindowsBinaries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in using newest versions of Node.js.
Try this https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36-x86.msi